# Getting the dynamic element id of div in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have set the id of the ng-repeat = objectId, ie

```
<div class="mainListLabel "  ng-if="profile==1" id={{obj.boeId}}
     ng-repeat="obj in mainList" 
     ng-click="getEmployeeInformation(obj.boeId)">{{obj.boedisplayName}}</div>
```

when I try to do

```
document.getElementById("1163").value, I get undefined
```

or when I do

```
angular.element('#1163').val(), I get ""
```

I am assuming the reason for this is because the script file is executed before the dynamic id is assigned, is there any way I can get the value from the elemental id

Comment: It is really bad form to do DOM manipulation in Angular - and is likely why you are having difficulty. You should bind the element value to a controller property and use the controller property. Can you describe what you are trying to achieve beyond `.getElementById()`?

Comment: Additionally, `<div>` elements don't have value properties - value properties only exist on HTMLInputElements

Comment: My requirement is to set the scroll to the record which was last updated in the list

Comment: @RandyCasburn  Yes the value does not exist for the div, but how can I set the scroll to the partiucular record when we go back to the list page from the detail page?

Answer (score 9):

`<div>` elements don't have value properties - value properties only exist on `HTMLInputElements`

---

As an (important) side note:

It is really bad form to do DOM manipulation in Angular - and is likely why you are having difficulty. You should bind the element value to a controller property and use the controller property.